Ag Grid angular
I am working on ag grid with angular need to customize the ag grid table header filter icon color how can do this in angular 17.
I want to change the header icon color
I am working on ag grid with angular need to customize the ag grid table header filter icon color how can do this in angular 17.
I want to change the header icon color

There are variables for customization header. For example (ag-theme-quartz is theme you are using) .ag-theme-quartz {--ag-header-foreground-color: red;}. Find more here: https://www.ag-grid.com/angular-data-grid/global-style-customisation-headers/
